# Python merging data in two files

Tags: python, regex

I have two text files. One text file is "numbers.txt". It contains 10 digit phone numbers, one on each line. The second file "users" contains data about several accounts. I only want to find info on the accounts listed in numbers.txt

So, for each number in numbers.txt search users file for said number. If found return that line of text and the following line of text (or return all text until next empty line would also work).

numbers.txt looks like:

```
1234567021
1234566792
```

users file looks like:

```
1234567021@host.com User-Password == "secret"
           Framed-IP-Address = 192.168.1.100,
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
1234567021 1234567021@host.com User-Password == "secret" Framed-IP-Address = 192.168.1.100
```

I'm stuck / stumped as to how to approach it. What I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

# Load numbers text file
if os.path.isfile("numbers.txt"):
    print "Loaded Numbers"
    #### Open file, if exists
    numbers = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
else:
    print "ERROR: Unable to read numbers.txt"
    quit()

# Load user data file
if os.path.isfile("users.txt"):
    print "Loaded user data"
    #### Open file, if exists
    users_data = open('users.txt', 'r')
else:
    print "ERROR: Unable to read users_data"
    quit()


#### Search 
if any(str(users_data) in s for s in numbers):
    for line in numbers:
        if number in line:
            #### Produce sanitized list of output
            output = line.split(' ')
            #print output[0]
            print output
            # also need next line from users_data
            # after each match 

#### Close numbers file and quit
numbers.close()
users_data.close()
quit()
```

Comment: What does 'Im stuck' mean?  Have you been through the through the [Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) in the documentation?- It may contain some useful information.

Comment: `any("@host" in s for s in numbers)` will always evaluate false - there is no `@host` string in numbers. change it to `users_data`.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong / how to approach the problem. In the search section I'm trying to iterate through the numbers in numbers.txt and search for said number(s) in users_data. Then print the data regarding that number.

Comment: By the way, the standard indentation for Python code is [four spaces, not six or eight](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: _Read_ the numbers into a set. Iterate over the lines of the 'users' file, if the first ten characters of a line is in the set then save the line and the next line, repeat.

Comment: Does the users file actually have the `\n` in the record of the user's information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the numbers into a set

```
with open('numbers.txt') as f:
    numbers = {line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()}
```

Look at the first ten characters of each line in `users.txt`. If that string is in `numbers`, save two lines to a container (`dict`)

```
result = dict()
with open('users.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key = line[:10]
        if key in numbers:
            value = line + f.next()
            result[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not optimal therefore have to read users_data numbers.txt lines times:

```
#### Search
for number in numbers:
    for data in users_data:
        if data.startswith(number):
            print (number, data)
```

Comment: The output is exactly what I'm going for. However, the phone number does not match with the data displayed. So, maybe need to sort the data first as btrbt stated.

Answer (score 0):

I just suggest you might can sort the data first, then we can loop for number in numbers. can find the number in the users_data.

Answer (score 0):

This is written in Python 3 to get the behavior of `StringIO` that I wanted.

Just change `with StringIO(nums_txt) as f:` to `open('numbers.txt') as f:` to use the name of the file of your nums file and same with the user file part. This should be obvious:

```
nums_txt='''\
1234567021
1234566792'''

users='''
1234567021@host.com User-Password == "secret"
           Framed-IP-Address = 192.168.1.100,
''' 

import re
from io import StringIO

with StringIO(nums_txt) as f:   # with open('numbers.txt') as f:  ...
    nums={line.strip():'Not Found' for line in f}

nfs={}    
with StringIO(users) as f:      # with open('users.txt') as f: ...
    for m in re.finditer(r'(^\d{10})(@.*?)(?=(?:\d{10}@)|\Z)', f.read(), re.S | re.M):
        rec=re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', ' '.join(m.group(2).splitlines()))
        if m.group(1) in nums:
            nums[m.group(1)]=rec
        else:
            nfs[m.group(1)]='Not Found'    
print(nums)
```

Prints:

```
{'1234567021': '@host.com User-Password == "secret" Framed-IP-Address = 192.168.1.100,', '1234566792': 'Not Found'}
```

Comments:

1. It is not obvious if the `users` file is formatted like that. Adjust the regex accordingly
2. Only works if the numbers in `numbers` are unique
3. Records in `users` without a corresponding number in `numbers` are gathered in the dict `nfs`